# Trigger-Problems in HeidiSQL with using MariaDB (Current_User)

Tags: java, sql, triggers, mariadb, heidisql

after hours of testing and searching for a solution of my trigger-problem without progress, I hope I'll get an advice from the community:

I created a database in MariaDB using HeidiSQL as frontend. Now, there's the possibility to create triggers, and I want to create an insert-trigger to get the User() - but it doesn't work. I get all the time "root@localhost" instead  of the User.

One Problem is, I cannot change the definer because it's a fixed parameter from HeidiSQL. I attached a few pictures of the frontend. When I change the definer in "user@%", I receive an error in my Java program as follows:

java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('User'@'%') does not exist

I also tried the function Current_User(), but unfortunately without success. In this case, I just receive the Name of the Definer of the trigger, but not the User() of the Database.

Thank you in advance for your support!

[Trigger without definer in HeidiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKMpB.png)

[Trigger with definer in HeidiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePVFg.png)

[Creating Trigger-Tool in HeidiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NePx.png)

Comment: I dont know anything about the specific tools you are using, but I suspect that the user connecting to the database is a system user, not the user running the app. For example if there is a service running thats connecting to the database, you would get the service's id, not the front end user id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it with system user and session user, and it's unfortunately the same. However, I get the correct Username when I do an Insert in my database directly in my SQL-Frontend. But, when I use my Java-File for an insert, there's still the "root-user".

Comment: Well thats what I would expect. Your sql front end will be connected to the database as you, but your java file will be connecting as a system user. Have a look at your connection strings if you can, or find the user in your front end app (or perhaps its available in your server app, dont know)  and pass it as a parameter to your sql call.

Comment: Sorry Tom for my missing answer! You was right - I checked my Connection - strings and there was a root-user… :-( I was so focused on my database that I Forget to check that first - Thank you!

Comment: So, I stored the username and the Password in my Document Controller to pass it through to the different Connection-Strings (getter-and setter-Methods), but I get the value "null", when I use the getter-Method in the other document Controller. First steps in programming can be really exhausting… Thanks!